# How can I set one value and change all others where a condition is met using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a system where posts can be added. When you edit a post you have the option so save it as a version. This way people can check back older versions of a text.

I'm trying to add the possibility to set the default text on a page.

All my texts in my database have a field called `active` which is 1 when the first text is added and 0 for any new versions that are made.

On my page which shows the text, the text with active = 1 is always shown, so I would like to be able to set a text to active while all other texts from the same category are set to 0 or inactive.

This way a user can choose which version is shown by default.

How can I do this?

My database layout:

[image]

As you can see there is a row called `parent_id` I only want to change all other values withing that id.

So let's say for example, I want to set `id` 4 to `1` then both `id` 1 and 5 need to be `0`. Only the `parent_id` 73 will be affected in this case.

How can I do this using SQL? I've seen some examples using `CASE` but those were another DB language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be using a case when  in set  clause

```
update  my_table 
set active = (case when id  = 4 then 1 else  0  end) 
where parent_id = 73
```